# change the Css of eventbrite calendar widget

Tags: eventbrite

HI can we change the styling of the calendar widget from Eventbrite.?
I need to adjust width, height and show event details on date click

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't change the CSS to Eventbrite's iFrame widgets.

You can replicated the features of the Widget and customize to your liking with Eventbrite's API.

Here is the developer center: http://developer.eventbrite.com/

You'll want to use this API method, /user_list_events: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_events/

Hope that helps!